# Subscription Membership

Tags: 7

User will key in particular info such as Name, contact and email.
User will choose membership package such as one month, 6 months or one year
Activation email will send to the user.
User will click on the link and redirect to paypal.
User will key in their payment info.
User will receive ID and password.

May I know how to create this logic into my website?

Comment: `May I know how to do these?` learn PHP, drupal forms, and read the paypal developer documentation.

Comment: May I know how to create this logic into my website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.drupal.org/project/moneysuite use this module

1)Enable membership suite submodule of moneysuite and also enable payment gateway (**paypal**).

2)goto admin/people/permissions/roles,create a unique role say(**premium membership**).

3)go to admin/config/people/accounts/fields,then add field to your registration page **"contact"**

4)then go to admin/structure/ms_products/ms_membership,there create membership plans ,you can show membership plans(one month, 6 months or one year)on user registration page and also assign the role which was previously created (**premium membership**)

5)after doing complete checkout process,user will get unique (**premium membership**) role who brought membership plans.

6)then create a page which can see only (**premium membership**)roles by setting permissions ,where User will receive ID and password.

Atlast I want to say i cant explain the entire process here above are the basic steps which are required to create any membership site.

Comment: thanks for your reply. When I register, I choose premium membership package and click register. It goes to blank page and nothing happen. Is there any tutorial I can learn from this module?

Comment: i think u diidnt enabled  payment gateway or checkout process

Comment: follow this link i think you will get some idea about it https://vimeo.com/22866377

Comment: when I click create account, it wont redirect to checkout. Even I follow the video still the same.

Comment: i think you are doing some mistake while configuring modules or creating membership plans ,i already devloped membership sites 2 times but i didnt find any problem while using this module